# Magento 2 : Custom online shipping method with shipping API

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, shipping, shipping-methods, custom-shipping-method

I am having a custom shipping API which I want to integrate with Magento version 2.2.x

Is there anyone having some knowledge how to create an online shipping method, how to call the custom API to generate the shipping cost and set dynamically, how to create a shipping?

Please help!

Comment: could you please share API link which you want you use ? Also what you have tried so far ?

Comment: @Pawan name of the shipping company is Redstar. They have shared the API in DOC. It is just some CURL request to generate shipping cost, shipping label. I don't have any idea about how to start a online shipping method in M2, when to call the API to generate shipping cost, how to display and etc.

Comment: could you please share URL where I can download that document. Will it need any active account Or Key ?

Comment: @Aveek have you done online shipping if done pls share how to implement i have fallowed some links but not shwoing in cart and checkout